# Deleting multiple attributes in Nifi

Tags: attributes, updates, apache-nifi

I am aware of how to delete a single attribute in Nifi, but what is the proper syntax to delete multiple attributes? Do I have to use multiple UpdateAttributes transformations or is there a delimiter I can use to separate the attributes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

The [UpdateAttribute](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-update-attribute-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.attributes.UpdateAttribute/index.html) processor's Delete Attribute Express is a regular expression, and you can delete multiple attributes with simple regex:

```
attribute1|attribute2|attribute3
```

or more complicated rules:

```
attribute\d
```