# Mass Delete of Attributes in a NiFi Data Flow

Tags: apache-nifi

I wish to perform a mass cleanup of flow file attributes in a NiFi data flow. I understand that this isn't absolutely necessary but rather it is a preference. Some processors such as ExecuteSQLRecord and InvokeHTTP add quite a few attributes for execution metrics. After I log these attributes, I do not wish to retain them. I do wish to retain the core attributes defined in the documentation, along with some that are critical to my data flow.

Currently, I am using an UpdateAttribute processor and setting the value of the "Delete Attributes Expression" with a value of something like `"^(?!(attribute1|attribute2|attribute3...|attributen)$).*$` where attribute1...attributen are the attributes I want to keep (mostly the core attributes but some that are critical to my data flow).

What I have seems to work just fine and it looks like this is essentially the way to do it as it was answered this way in another question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44956539/deleting-multiple-attributes-in-nifi)). My question is whether there is a *better* way to do the same thing.

Comment: you have to explain why current approach is not good enough for you.

Comment: @daggett - It is not that my approach is not "good enough". It is just that I am new to NiFi (I have only been working with it for about two weeks now) and I want to make sure I am not going to run into issues down the road when I throw this thing into production if I continue using this solution, hence why I asked if there was a better way to do it.

Comment: Updateattribute is a native processor that works fast. It's absolutely normal to remove unused attributes. The only other way I could imagine to manipulate attributes is script and I don't see any reason to use it.